# MySQL Count to rows as one

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database as laid out below.

```
mysql> select * from wants where itemname='lamp' order by location;
+------+--------------------+-------------+----------+----------+----------+
| sess | username           | room        | image    | item     | priority |
+------+--------------------+-------------+----------+----------+----------+
|   33 | user1@aol.com      | Family Room | DSC00649 | Lamp     |        1 |
|  235 | user2@yahoo.com    | Family Room | DSC00649 | Lamp     |        2 |
|   60 | user3@homtmail.com | Foyer       | DSC00527 | Lamp     |        1 |
|  197 | user4@gmail.com    | Foyer       | DSC00527 | Lamp     |        2 |
|  189 | user4@gmail.com    | Living Room | DSC00827 | Lamp     |        1 |
|  273 | user5@live.com     | Living Room | DSC00827 | Lamp     |        2 |
+------+--------------------+-------------+----------+----------+----------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

What I am trying to do is get a count of each item per room.

When I run the query it should look like:

```
2 Family Room Lamp user1@aol.com user2@yahoo.com 
2 Foyer Lamp user3@homtmail.com user4@gmail.com
2 Living Room Lamp user4@gmail.com user5@live.com
```

Current Query:

```
$result1 = mysql_query("SELECT username, location, image, itemname, COUNT( itemname ) x  FROM wants GROUP BY itemname HAVING x >1 order by location ASC")
```

This will give the following output:

```
6 Family Room Lamp luser1@aol.com user2@yahoo.com user3@homtmail.com user4@gmail.com user4@gmail.com user5@live.com
```

I tried to use Concat to get the count of the first two rows but that did not help,

How can i break these out to get the rooms to read separately, when the Item name is the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `group by` the room instead of the item.  Also sounds like you're looking for `group_concat` to list the users:

```
select count(*), 
       room,
       group_concat(username)
from wants
where item ='lamp'
group by room
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4bde0/2)